# Updating to PHP 5.4 on Debian

Tags: php, linux, debian

Figured there would be an easy answer on Google, but no luck.  Most of the tutorials, while similar to what I need, don't work on Debian:

http://chemicaloliver.net/internet/installing-php-5-4-in-ubuntu/

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
```

yields:

```
-bash: add-apt-repository: command not found
```

Comment: Trying asking on http://serverfault.com/ - you'll also need to know what version of Debian you're running before asking.....

Comment: You will also have to detail on what problem you are facing. What from the given URL is not working for you?

Comment: PPAs are an Ubuntu-specific feature. Doesn't exist in Debian.

Comment: Just FYI: http://serverfault.com/questions/404815/how-can-i-upgrade-php-to-a-higher-version-for-debian-squeeze

Answer (score 4):

have you tried the [dotdeb repository](http://vjetnamnet.com/how-to-install-php-5-4-on-debian-using-dotdeb-repository/)?

Comment: apt-get update

yielded

    N: Ignoring file 'dotdeb.gpg' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
    N: Ignoring file 'dotdeb.gpg.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
    E: Type 'Deb' is not known on line 1 in sources list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list
    E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: you don't have to add the .gpg file in sources.list, only `deb http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze-php54 all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze-php54 all` and add the gpg key to apt

Answer (score -1):

Deal with everything easier by using Xampp for Linux if your system is local or developing machine.

Use the following URL to get the latest version that has PHP version 5.4.7

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html

Comment: Already have it - I was attempting to upgrade a development environment for multiple users.

Comment: Xampp could be installed to run for multiple users.

Answer (score -1):

Try to edit the `dotdeb.list` file;

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotdeb.list
```

then paste the following mirrors:

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze-php54 all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze-php54 all
```

next it should be necessary to execute as follow:

```
gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 89DF5277
gpg -a --export 89DF5277 | apt-key add -
```

and

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```